# hover effect on div using jquery

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="section one"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="section two"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="section three"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="section four"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

On hover each div ( section ) it should hide and the next div( inner ) should  display. On mouseleave it show as old.
For this I use moseenter and mouseleave events.

**Problem**

On mouseenter the div blinks (happends the both events together).

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".inner").hide();
    $(".section").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next(".inner").show();
    });
    $(".section").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).show();
        $(this).next(".inner").hide();
    });
});
```

Please check the fiddle given below for more details

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hdehzec0/7/)

Comment: Of course. jQuery's `hide()` method sets the element's CSS `display` property to "none". When this happens the element is effectively removed from the page, meaning that you're no longer hovering over it as it's no longer there.

Comment: here your [fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/hdehzec0/15/) have look and tell me what ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hdehzec0/13/

Comment: put the mouseleave event on ".inner" instead of ".section", here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hdehzec0/14/

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay, all comments and answers are very helpful and I can find the solution. Thanks to all...

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because of the `.hide` is also firing the `mouse out` function..

Here is your updated Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/hdehzec0/12/**

*Consider this structure for your HTML:*

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="section one"><div class="inner"></div></div>

    <div class="section two"><div class="inner"></div></div>

    <div class="section three"><div class="inner"></div></div>

    <div class="section four"><div class="inner"></div></div>

</div>
```

*and your JQuery :*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".inner").hide();
    $(".section").hover(
     function () {
        $(this).find(".inner").show();
     }, function() {
        $(this).find(".inner").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As the ".section" is hidden, your mouse leaves the .section. This is why it blinks.
And as you show a `.hidden`, you need to fire your event when you leave the `.hidden`
Here is something that may solve your issue: 
(**http://jsfiddle.net/hdehzec0/7/**) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".inner").hide();
    $(".section").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).next(".inner").show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $(".inner").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $(".section").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hdehzec0/16/

When you enter .section it disappears therefore mouseleave function gets triggered. Instead of using .section on mouseleave use .inner since your mouse is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".inner").hide();
        $(".section").mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).next(".inner").show();
        });
        $(".inner").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).prev(".section").show();
        }); 

});
```